# Set an array value equal to a variable in a dynamically loaded class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, variables, dynamic

I have a seemingly simple question that I have not been able to find a solution in about a week of searching, so I thought I'd ask. I want to take an array value, say `anArray[1]`
and set it equal to a variable in another class... `otherClass.variableOne`

This is easy to do, but I want to be able to use a variable for the name of the class i want the variable from. So instead of "otherClass.variableOne" i want something like:

```
String classVar = "otherClass";    
anArray[1]=classVar.variableOne;
```

I'm not sure whether i need to set classVar equal to something like... `className(otherClass)` or something like that. I am quite new to Java and I'm having great difficulty.

I know this seems dumb but it is necessary for what I want to do. I have looked into reflection but it doesn't seem to able to do what I need. Essentially my question is:

```
String classVar = "otherClass";
anArray[1]=classVar.variableOne
```

How do i make something like that work where classVar is a variable that refers to a class that contains the public static int variableOne?

Please excuse limited programming experience. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [the Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect). You can use it to obtain a `Class` variable representing "OtherClass" (e.g., `Class.forName("com.example.OtherClass"`) and then go through its fields and methods, and even create new instances of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your question compeltely, so excuse me if my answer is not useful. If you simply need to assign the value of a `public static int variableOne` then you can do this by accessing the variable in a static way. Accessing the variable in a `static` way means simply use the classname.staticVariable to get the variable value. I believe this is what you need:

```
anArray[1]=OtherClassName.variableOne
```

replace the ClassName and variableName with your actual classname and variable name.

Read this to understand more about class and instance variables: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: This is what i need to do, but instead of saying 'OtherClassName' i want to use a variable for that. I actually have 33 array values, and therefore if i could just change the variable and make it so that all of the array values would now call the classVariable.variableOne that is preferable.